# Charts.js line chart, how to hide y-axis start and end label if data is same

Tags: javascript, linechart, chart.js

I am new to Charts.js and I have been looking for information how to hide/remove y-axis start and end labels (below and above) if data returned all same horizontal line. Does anyone know?

Here is an example.

(y-axis)

67878196

67878195 ----o----o----o----o----o

67878194 ================= (x-axis)

I would like to hide/remove start and end labels and just display 67878195. Any advice and tips are appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: you can remove the x-axis labels by emptying the labels array in your options object, and then to re-add them later on condition. I'm trying to do a similar thing right now and I'm not so sure you can hide/remove the y-axis. if it's that important you can go to the github page and request a feature

Comment: I have tried but no luck so far. I will leave it as it is for now. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 4):

Hope this helps you: 
(It hides first and last labels in y axis)

```
var myChart2 = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas2"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {
   responsive: true,
title: {
  display: true,
  text: "Chart.js - Modified Chart Hiding Min/Max"
},
tooltips: {
  mode: 'index',
  intersect: false
},
legend: {
  display: false,
},
scales: {
  yAxes: [{
    afterTickToLabelConversion: function(scaleInstance) {
      // set the first and last tick to null so it does not display
      // note, ticks[0] is the last tick and ticks[length - 1] is the first
      scaleInstance.ticks[0] = null;
      scaleInstance.ticks[scaleInstance.ticks.length - 1] = null;

      // need to do the same thing for this similiar array which is used internally
      scaleInstance.ticksAsNumbers[0] = null;
      scaleInstance.ticksAsNumbers[scaleInstance.ticksAsNumbers.length - 1] = null;
    },
    ticks: {
      min: 10,
      max: 90,
    },
  }],
}
 }});
```

complete code on : https://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/jBeWWN

Comment: This is beauty! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If this works for you, please accept it as correct answer.